# How can I open the editor when I click browser or nodejs console file path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

For example, In my website I have print absolute file path using `console.log`
like this
`console.log('/user/myname/work/projectName/index.ts')`
I want to open the file in the editor when I click the message in the devtool in the chrome.

If I log it in nodejs how can I do the same thing?

`node index.js`

```
console.log(__dirname)
```

I want to open the __dirname file using current editor maybe vscode or webtorm and so on when I click the message in the terminal.

How can I do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `console.log(/user/myname/work/projectName/index.ts)` won't even execute ... did you mean `console.log("/user/myname/work/projectName/index.ts")` - so, given you'ev console.loged `"/user/myname/work/projectName/index.ts"` - how does that "refer" to a file on YOUR computer

Comment: @JaromandaX My fault, edited

Comment: @JaromandaX Assume I write the path as const string, It means I am in developing mode

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in most cases (most of the terminal apps already support this functionality for a long time out-of-the-box) is to prepend a correct protocol before the file path, so that the logged path becomes a **file URI**.

More on file URIs here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

In your case, you can just prepend `file://` to the path and it should work out of the box, e.g.:

```
file:///Users/someuser/somefile.txt
```

Note that I used standard Unix/MacOS pathname for the example. The first two slashes depict the protocol (`file://`), the next one comes from the root path in the filesystem, this will look different in e.g. Windows environment.

So, if you want to use `__dirname` (note that you can still add other text to the logged message, file URI just has to be a part of it):

```js
console.log(`I will be opening file://${__dirname}`);
```

This works due to the support of hyperlinks in terminal emulators. If you want to delve deeper into the topic, follow this GIST:
https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda